# Is there a version of list.sort() that returns the sorted list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, random, shuffle

I'm trying to perform an inline operation where I need to sort a list as part of the process.
The `sort` function of `list` type objects operates on the list it was called on instead of returning the result.

The [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) confirms this:

> **list.sort()**
>   Sort the items of the list, in place.

I tried this through Python command-line and here's the result:

```
>>> a = list("hello").sort()
>>> print a
None
>>> b = list("hello")
>>> print b
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> b.sort()
>>> print b
['e', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Is there a way to skip around this issue and make a line such as the following possible?

```
result = list(random.choice(basesalts)).sort()
```

Using the code above would help me reduce the length and verbosity of my code.

Comment: "seems to operate on the list it was called".  That's wrong.  It doesn't "seem to".  It's defined that way.  No exceptions.  That's the way it's supposed to work. `list.sort()` does not return a value; it modifies the list. `result= ....sort()` can never work.  By definition.

Comment: "seem to confirm this:"  That's wrong.  They actually confirm this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's the built-in [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> a = sorted(list('hello'))
>>> a
['e', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Also notice that you don't need `list()` anymore:

```
>>> sorted('hello')
['e', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Since `basesalts` seems to be a list of strings, you can just do:

```
result = sorted(random.choice(basesalts))
```

If that is the kind of output you're looking for.

Comment: `sorted(foo)` being essentially `temp = list(foo); temp.sort(); return temp` there is technically no need to convert a string to a list before passing it to `sorted()`.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

Use [sorted](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted).

> It Return a new sorted list from the items in iterable.

```
>>> a = sorted(list('hello'))
>>> a
['e', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>>
```

The difference is that the list.sort() method is only defined for lists. In contrast, the sorted() function accepts any iterable.

So, you can do

```
>>> a = sorted('hello')
>>> a
['e', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>>
```

Take a look at this nice article [Sorting Mini-HOW TO](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).

Answer (score 0):

Sorted is your friend here. It's not a member function of the list class it's a built in function that takes a list as an argument.

The class list has no sort function.

```
list1 = [ 1, 4, 5, 2]
print sorted(list1)

>> [1, 2, 4, 5]
```